# Cell protection only for cells with formulas when saved in a new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which contains sheets with formulas in some of the cells. I want to protect the cells containing these formulas from editing, but I don't want to protect the non-formula containing cells. When I save the worksheet I want the cell protection for the formulas to propagate to the new worksheet.

for example Consider my workbook A containing two sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2).

```
Sub protect()
Dim pwd As String

pwd = InputBox("entrer a password", Title:="Password")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Cells.Select
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect pwd, True, True, True, True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="myfile1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Copy
    Cells.Select
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect pwd, True, True, True, True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="myfile2"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

 End Sub
```

When I run this code all the cells (which contains formulas or not) of both "myfile1" and "myfile2" are  protected. I only want to protect the cells which contain formulas.

How do I accomplish just protecting only the cells with formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all cells in a worksheet are locked. You can change them because the worksheet is not protected. You do not need to lock the formulas; you need to **unlock** the blanks and constants.

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = False
```

Relying on [Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) and [Worksheet.Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx)
 and naming your sub procedure the same as the primary command that you are running are not good ideas.

```
Sub myProtect()
    Dim pwd As String, s As Long

    pwd = InputBox("entrer a password", Title:="Password")

    With ThisWorkbook
        For s = 1 To 2
            With .Worksheets("Sheet" & s)
                .Copy
            End With

            With ActiveWorkbook
                With .Worksheets(1)
                    .UsedRange
                    On Error Resume Next    '<~~just in case there are no constants or blanks
                    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
                    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = False
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .protect pwd, True, True, True, True
                End With
                .SaveAs Filename:="myfile" & s, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        Next s
    End With

 End Sub
```

I've looped the actions to reduce redundant code. Depending on your actual naming conventions, you might have to make some changes.

Please note that when unlocking the `.Cells`, you are only referring to cells within the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). This may have to be modified if you want to unlock a larger range of cells.

Comment: I had  it but i dont get the desired result

Comment: See full rewrite above.

Comment: My sheets contains ActiveX Controls. And when i export, for exemple the Sheet1, the created command Button doesnt work when i clik on it but it work on the original Workbook A. How can i fixe it?

Comment: For starters, you would have to [.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) a FileFormat:=[xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). The xlOpenXMLWorkbook does not contain macros.